# jquery version compatibilty issue unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I am using `jquery-1.7.1` and I need to upgrade upon my client's request to `jquery-1.12.0`.

I get the following error when I do so :

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #dragAndDropFiles input[name=Sans titre][type=text]

So that means that the downgraded jquery version doesn't understand this :

```
$("#dragAndDropFiles input[name=No Title][type=text]").val()
```

Can someone help me to understand why is this expression an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a whitespace in the attribute value you need to use it like name='No Title':

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($("#dragAndDropFiles input[name='No Title'][type=text]").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragAndDropFiles">
  <input name="No Title" type="text" value="myval" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('#dragAndDropFiles input[name="No Title"][type=text]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragAndDropFiles">
  <input name="No Title" type="text" value="check value" />
</div>
```

Use ' or " alternatively.